# Angular UI Grid - select all based on filter

Tags: javascript, angular-ui-grid

I am currently using ui-grid and have run into a small problem. I want to be able to `select all` the items based on filters I have set within the grid. For example, if I do a `select all` without a filter, 500 items will be selected. Then, if I filter a column and `select all`, 500 items are again selected instead of the items that are currently being shown.

My select all logic is very simple per the ui-grid documentation:

```
$scope.selectAll = function () {
    $scope.gridApi.selection.selectAllRows();
};

$scope.clearAll = function () {
    $scope.gridApi.selection.clearSelectedRows();
};
```

The reason I want this is because I'm working on a mass delete - the ability to filter down the grid to items you can then delete simply by clicking `select all` and then `delete`.

Answer (score 1):

You could try selectAllVisibleRows.  http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.selection.api:PublicApi